# When calling findAndRemove, what are the happy and error return types?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I want to understand what calling .findAndRemove(document("userId" -> userId)) will return when:

1. document exists
2. document doesn't exist

Code:

```
userColl.findAndRemove(document("userId" => userId)).map(r => ...)
```

I want to return either a success, or a failure with the reason it failed.

I know there are the following values returned:

```
r.value
r.lastError
r.result[A]
```

I'm not sure how to return the correct value after calling findAndRemove and mapping on it.

Comment: Not sure what's unclear. If an error occurred, `lastError` describes it, otherwise it is None. 
If document was found `value` is set (and `result` can be used to read it) otherwise it is None.

Comment: You said "otherwise it is none" 2 times, so how to determine a success if value is not set or lastError is not defined?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "success". There are three possible states: (1) error (`lastError` is set) (plus, possibly a "1a" - document found, but failed to get deleted - when both `lastError` and `value` are set ... I don't know if this is possible); (2) operation successful (`lastError` unset), but document is not found (`value` is unset); (3) object found (`value` is set) and successfully deleted (`lastError` is unset).

Comment: The version is not indicated. W/o that, it's impossible to have proper answer. Also, please first have a look at the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/tutorial/write-documents.html)